# Rename Json object fieldName

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

i am using MVC c#
i have a object with

```
public class Person
{
        public int TypeId { get; set; }
        public string Code { get; set; }

}
```

i have a code that retruns JSON object for this object like this

```
    return Json(personCodeStore.GetBusinessCodes());
```

But when I receive this on the client side i want to be able to rename the field name from

```
TypeId to value
Code  to text
```

I do not want to use DataContractSerializer like [MVC3 JSON Serialization: How to control the property names?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7260924/mvc3-json-serialization-how-to-control-the-property-names)
because i am using EF 5.x and every time i update the model and .tt file runs it overwrites my changes and also it uses this modified property on all my views which i don't want.

So is there a way i can rename this when i serialize it or once i get on client side using jquery?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could simply use LINQ and return an anonymous object projecting your original result:

```
var businessCodes = personCodeStore.GetBusinessCodes();
return Json(businessCodes.Select(x => new 
{
    value = x.TypeId,
    text = x.Code
}));
```

Now you're gonna get something along the lines of:

```
[
    { "value": 1, text = "text 1" },
    { "value": 2, text = "text 2" },
    { "value": 3, text = "text 3" }
    ...
]
```