# MVC JsonResult camelCase serialization

Tags: json, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, serialization, camelcasing

I am trying to make my action return a JsonResult where all its properties are in camelCase.

I have a simply model:

```
public class MyModel
{
    public int SomeInteger { get; set; }

    public string SomeString { get; set; }
}
```

And a simple controller action:

```
public JsonResult Index()
    {
        MyModel model = new MyModel();
        model.SomeInteger = 1;
        model.SomeString = "SomeString";

        return Json(model, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

Calling this action method now returns a JsonResult containing the following data:

```
{"SomeInteger":1,"SomeString":"SomeString"}
```

For my uses i need the action return the data in camelCase, somehow like this:

```
{"someInteger":1,"someString":"SomeString"}
```

Is there any elegant way to do this?

I was looking into possible solutions around here and found [MVC3 JSON Serialization: How to control the property names?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7260924/mvc3-json-serialization-how-to-control-the-property-names) where they set DataMember definitions to every property of the model, but I do not really want to do this.

Also I found a link where they say that it is possible to solve exactly this kind of issue: http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/json-and-xml-serialization#json_camelcasing. It says:

**To write JSON property names with camel casing, without changing your data model, set the CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver on the serializer:**

```
var json = GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.JsonFormatter;
json.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver();
```

One entry on this blog http://frankapi.wordpress.com/2012/09/09/going-camelcase-in-asp-net-mvc-web-api/ also mentiones this solution and states you can simply add it to the **RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes** to fix this issue. I tried it, but I couldn't make it work.

Do you guys have any idea where I was doing something wrong?

Comment: What do mean on "I tried it, but I couldn't make it work."?

Comment: I added that code snippet to the RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes method but it seemed to have no effect because the JsonResult still contained the same data.

Comment: FYI, the `CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver` only works with WebAPI controllers (controllers that extend `ApiController`).

Comment: yet, is there any other workaround to achieve this for a normal controller?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The Json functions of the Controller are just wrappers for creating JsonResults:

```
protected internal JsonResult Json(object data)
{
    return Json(data, null /* contentType */, null /* contentEncoding */, JsonRequestBehavior.DenyGet);
}

protected internal JsonResult Json(object data, string contentType)
{
    return Json(data, contentType, null /* contentEncoding */, JsonRequestBehavior.DenyGet);
}

protected internal virtual JsonResult Json(object data, string contentType, Encoding contentEncoding)
{
    return Json(data, contentType, contentEncoding, JsonRequestBehavior.DenyGet);
}

protected internal JsonResult Json(object data, JsonRequestBehavior behavior)
{
    return Json(data, null /* contentType */, null /* contentEncoding */, behavior);
}

protected internal JsonResult Json(object data, string contentType, JsonRequestBehavior behavior)
{
    return Json(data, contentType, null /* contentEncoding */, behavior);
}

protected internal virtual JsonResult Json(object data, string contentType, Encoding contentEncoding, JsonRequestBehavior behavior)
{
    return new JsonResult
    {
        Data = data,
        ContentType = contentType,
        ContentEncoding = contentEncoding,
        JsonRequestBehavior = behavior
    };
}
```

JsonResult internally uses JavaScriptSerializer, so you don't have control about the serialisation process:

```
public class JsonResult : ActionResult
{
    public JsonResult()
    {
        JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.DenyGet;
    }

    public Encoding ContentEncoding { get; set; }

    public string ContentType { get; set; }

    public object Data { get; set; }

    public JsonRequestBehavior JsonRequestBehavior { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// When set MaxJsonLength passed to the JavaScriptSerializer.
    /// </summary>
    public int? MaxJsonLength { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// When set RecursionLimit passed to the JavaScriptSerializer.
    /// </summary>
    public int? RecursionLimit { get; set; }

    public override void ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context)
    {
        if (context == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("context");
        }
        if (JsonRequestBehavior == JsonRequestBehavior.DenyGet &&
            String.Equals(context.HttpContext.Request.HttpMethod, "GET", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException(MvcResources.JsonRequest_GetNotAllowed);
        }

        HttpResponseBase response = context.HttpContext.Response;

        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(ContentType))
        {
            response.ContentType = ContentType;
        }
        else
        {
            response.ContentType = "application/json";
        }
        if (ContentEncoding != null)
        {
            response.ContentEncoding = ContentEncoding;
        }
        if (Data != null)
        {
            JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
            if (MaxJsonLength.HasValue)
            {
                serializer.MaxJsonLength = MaxJsonLength.Value;
            }
            if (RecursionLimit.HasValue)
            {
                serializer.RecursionLimit = RecursionLimit.Value;
            }
            response.Write(serializer.Serialize(Data));
        }
    }
}
```

You have to create your own JsonResult and write your own Json Controller functions (if you need / want that). You can create new ones or overwrite existing ones, it is up to you. This [link](http://yobriefca.se/blog/2010/11/20/better-json-serialisation-for-asp-dot-net-mvc/) might also interest you.

Comment: The linked article helped me out. For anyone who tries it, the third constructor of JsonNetResult is missing setting the ResponseBody property. You can just add " : this(responseBody)" to the end of the third constructor.

Answer (score 17):

If you want to return a json string from your action which adheres to camelcase notation what you have to do is to create a JsonSerializerSettings instance and pass it as the second parameter of JsonConvert.SerializeObject(a,b) method.

```
public string GetSerializedCourseVms()
    {
        var courses = new[]
        {
            new CourseVm{Number = "CREA101", Name = "Care of Magical Creatures", Instructor ="Rubeus Hagrid"},
            new CourseVm{Number = "DARK502", Name = "Defence against dark arts", Instructor ="Severus Snape"},
            new CourseVm{Number = "TRAN201", Name = "Transfiguration", Instructor ="Minerva McGonal"}
        };
        var camelCaseFormatter = new JsonSerializerSettings();
        camelCaseFormatter.ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver();
        return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(courses, camelCaseFormatter);
    }
```