# ASP.NET MVC Data annotations for json key

Tags: json, asp.net-mvc

I Have a model in ASP.Net MVC something like this one.

```
public class DataTable
        {
            public int RecordsTotal { get; set; }

            public int RecordsFiltered { get; set; }

            public int Draw { get; set; }

        }
```

It is possible to output this as a JSON with putting a Data Annotation in every property?
The output should be something like this.

```
{
recordsTotal:10,
recordsFiltered:10,
draw:1 
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: What data annotations would you like to add, exactly?

Comment: Data annotation that will transform `RecordsTotal` into a key `recordsTotal`.
When returning a json to client/browser.

Comment: Is the only difference here capitalization? Otherwise, returning a JSON object will take care of that by default: `{ RecordsTotal:10, RecordsFiltered:10, Draw:1 }`

Comment: Yes, the only thing that I want is returning it as a CamelCase.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can return an object that looks exactly like the one you posted aside from the capital letter at the beginning:

```
return Json(new DataTable() {
    RecordsTotal = 10,
    RecordsFiltered = 10,
    Draw = 1
});
```

If you *really* need a lowercase property name [then there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1302946/asp-net-mvc-controlling-serialization-of-property-names-with-jsonresult) are [existing questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2789593/force-lowercase-property-names-from-json-in-asp-net-mvc) that [answer this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7260924/mvc3-json-serialization-how-to-control-the-property-names).