# HttpContext.Request.Form does not contain posted values in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, httprequest

The following is an example how i am posting data to a controller action in MVC.The data is perfectly populating to my model object and working fine.

```
var data={};
data.SearchText = 'abc'
data.SearchText1 = 'abcd'
var contentType = 'application/json; charset=utf-8';

$.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      cache: false,
      contentType: contentType,
      url: User/_UserList,
      data: JSON.stringify(data),
      success: successHandlerFunction,
      complete: completeHandlerFunction
});

[HttpPost]
public JsonResult _UserList(SearchViewModel model)
{
    var  users= "" ; //Get Data from DB ;
    return Json(users, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

But in case of an exception  i am trying to fetch value of model

```
public void OnException(ExceptionContext filterContext)
{


//filterContext.HttpContext.Request.Form -- is not giving any value
//filterContext.HttpContext.Request.QueryString -- is also having no value
//filterContext.HttpContext.Request.Params -- also no value about model

}
```

Can anybody give me a clue why the above piece of code not working

Comment: Do you get a exception?

Comment: is your model global variable in class?

Comment: Should not it be "protected override void OnException"?

Comment: Hi Voo,OnException is a implementation  from IExceptionFilter interface.

Comment: @Mukund,model is the parameter name of _UserList action,@Rahul I am not getting any exception

Comment: @ShuvenduDas Do you have  "filters.Add(new HandleErrorAttribute());" in your global code?

Answer (score 2):

Sorry - can't comment your answer, so placing a new answer.
The solution is right - you should make the contentType as  'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'. The reason is clearly described here:  [HttpRequest.Form Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.form(v=vs.110).aspx)

> The Form property is populated when the HTTP request Content-Type value is either "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" or "multipart/form-data".

As for 'JSON.stringify(data),' - that will make one string from the dictionary actually and in this case HttpRequest.Form cannot be populated as it requires a dictionary, basically, just 'data'.

Comment: Yeah I got it.But just wanted to know if we post data with contentType 'application/json; charset=utf-8' ,Then How one can  get the posted data from the Request object or is there any other way to retrieve the posted data

Comment: I tried the following function to extract the JSON Data still I am not able to fetch the json data from request object.  private string GetJsonContents(System.Web.HttpRequestBase Request)
        {
            string JsonContents;
            
            using (Stream receiveStream = Request.InputStream)
            {
                using (StreamReader readStream = new StreamReader(receiveStream))
                {
                    JsonContents = readStream.ReadToEnd();
                }
            }
            return JsonContents;
        }

Comment: But why do you need to extract Json data from a raw HttpRequest? Especially, if we're talking about ASP.NET MVC. Maybe it will be better to use something like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1302946/asp-net-mvc-controlling-serialization-of-property-names-with-jsonresult)?

Answer (score 0):

By Changing the contentType from 'application/json; charset=utf-8' to 
'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' the HttpContext.Request.Form started populating the value.We also need to remove the JSON.stringify while passing the data.

If we post the data with  contentType 'application/json; charset=utf-8' .And from the request object we need to retrieve the Json Contents then we can use the following piece of code

```
 private string GetJsonContents(System.Web.HttpRequestBase Request)
    {
        string JsonContents = string.Empty;
        try
        {
            using (Stream receiveStream = Request.InputStream)
            {
                using (StreamReader readStream = new StreamReader(receiveStream))
                {
                    receiveStream.Seek(0, System.IO.SeekOrigin.Begin);
                    JsonContents = readStream.ReadToEnd();
                }
            }
        }
        catch
        {
        }
        return JsonContents;
    }
```

Then we can use the following code to get the JSON Object

```
 string requestData = GetJsonContents(HttpContext.Current.Request);
 dynamic jsonObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(requestData);//using Newtonsoft dll
```